# Put a TextView in the center of an ImageView?

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I have an ImageView that is bigger than a TextView, and I want to center the TextView on top of the ImageView, both vertically and horizontally.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap both in a RelativeLayout and give TextView the desired layout parameters with respect to the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the textview after the imageview in the layout and give it negative margins

android:layout_marginTop="-10px"
android:layout_marginLeft="-10px"

or you could just use a text view and give it a drawable background

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FrameLayout` to center both of them:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/marker_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:src="@drawable/asphalt_ic_selected" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marker_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:text="A" />

</FrameLayout>
```